# How to sum elements in a nested list?

Tags: python

I want to sum elements I [1] (second elements in each list) in the nested list so that it doesn't exceed 23, i.e. <= 23 and create a sublist from that. Now I only get the same list, but I want a list where the total value doesn't exceed 23:

```
this = [['A', 5, 310],['B', 3, 270], ['C', 4.5, 220], ['D', 1, 150], ['E', 3.5, 140], ['F', 2.5, 90], ['G', 4, 70], ['H', 3, 60], ['I', 2, 50], ['J', 1, 30]]

max_weight = [i for i in this if i[1]<=23]
print(max_weight)
```

Comment: but the whole list is a total of 29, can you post a sample of the results you want?

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do a sum from all items?

```py
max_weight = sum(i[1] for i in this if i[1]<=23)
print(max_weight) #29.5
```

EDIT:

i think you want to do this, (I'm not sure if its possible to do in a one-liner)

```py
this = [['A', 5, 310],['B', 3, 270], ['C', 4.5, 220], ['D', 1, 150], ['E', 3.5, 140], ['F', 2.5, 90], ['G', 4, 70], ['H', 3, 60], ['I', 2, 50], ['J', 1, 30]]

total = 0
new = []

for i in this:
    total += i[1]
    if total <= 23:
        new.append(i)

print(new) #[['A', 5, 310], ['B', 3, 270], ['C', 4.5, 220], ['D', 1, 150], ['E', 3.5, 140], ['F', 2.5, 90]]
```

Comment: Yes that is what I wanna do! but unfortunately I don't get the same output as you

Comment: The output should be for example like this: sublist = [['A', 5, 310],['B', 3, 270], ['C', 4.5, 220], ['D', 1, 150], ['E', 3.5, 140], ['F', 2.5, 90], ['H', 3, 60]]